# Error message customization in file upload

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Using the guide http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html i'm trying to customize error message, but i've a problem: variable `errors` is not defined, as we don't validate an entity and we are not calling `$this->get('validator')->validate($entity)`.

```
{% block field_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {# errors is undefined here #}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_errors %}
```

This is the sample code:

```
public function uploadAction()
{
    $document = new Document();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
        ->add('name')
        ->add('file')
        ->getForm()
    ;

    if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

            $em->persist($document);
            $em->flush();

            $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('...'));
        }
    }

    // Variable 'errors' is not assigned
    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand.  If you are following the example then $document has validation rules on it which will be tested by $form->isValid().  {{ form_errors(form) }} should output any errors.

If it is just a template customization question then you need to test for the existence of errors before trying to process them:

```
{% block field_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
    <span style="color:red">
        {% for error in errors %}
            {{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators') }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_errors %}
```

Comment: What i mean is why `errors` is defined even if i'm not passing it to the view.

Comment: That is part of the form system.  It actually ends up inside of your formView object which you do pass.  If you want to know exactly how that all works then you could probably start with: Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension.  But the rendering process is difficult to follow.

Comment: Ok got it! But afaik `field_errors` is called either for field errors and for form errors. What if one want to show <ul> for form errors and <p> for field errors. Is this possible?

Comment: I.m sure it's possible but I never really investigated it that closely.